# Python ast col_offset for With node

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

`ast.With` node has strange `col_offset` value in python2 - it provides offset of the enclosed expression instead of `with` statement offset.

Is it a bug or feature? Are there any more nodes with the same behaviour in both py2/py3?

```
import ast


def node_offset(src):
    node = ast.parse(src).body[0]
    print(node.col_offset, node.__class__.__name__)


node_offset('print(1)')
node_offset('raise  fd')
node_offset('with  exp: return 1')
```

py2 output:

```
(0, 'Print')
(0, 'Raise')
(6, 'With') <- offset of the 'exp'
```

py3 output:

```
0 'Print'
0 'Raise'
0 'With' <- looks correct to me
```

Comment: I am unsure of the real significance of `col_offset` either and google is no help. When I replace a node using either `NodeTransformer` without using `copy_location` or just a manual replace (`tree.node.subnode.elt = ast.Object...`), I have to run `fix_missing_locations()`, which does not rewrite the offsets of objects later in the tree; yet the resulting ast compiles and execs correctly.